# Number of ways to travel from 1 to n in this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

You can move from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and so on, step by step, till 100.
Also, between the points give below, you can move directly within every pair:

(10 and 60)

(50 and 100)

(70 and 100)

(80 and 100)

How many different paths exist?
I tried it, and could find only 7. But a c-program i created says 8 paths. so, what do you think?

Here are the 7 paths in could find:

1-2-3....99-100;

1-2-3....10-60-61-62....100;

1-2-3....50-100;

1-2-3....10-60-61-62....70-100;

1-2-3....10-60-61-62....80-100;

1-2-3....70-100;

1-2-3....80-100;

Comment: Are you imposing a restriction that you cannot go backwards, e.g. from 60 to 59?  That you can only visit a node at most once?

Comment: If that was the case, then there would be too many paths. So, that's not the case.

Comment: The reason I ask, apart from wanting the Question to be well-posed, is that if you allow going backwards but restrict to visiting a node at most once, an additional solution can be found (which you seem to be asking for the Reader to find).

Comment: Okay, great! That was what i was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely the "missing" path steps from 1 to 10, jumps to 60, steps backward to 50 and jumps from there to 100.

This shows a concise set of rules for allowable paths is important, since one interpretation would disallow going backward by steps from 60 to 50.